# In c#, how to convert T? to T

Tags: c#, kotlin, nullable

Similar code works fine in kotlin but not work in c#

```cs
public static class Helper
{
    public static T RequireNotNll<T>(T? obj,string? message) {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new Exception(message ?? "obj must not null");
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` has different meanings for value types and for reference types. The latter applies only in a [nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), (`#nullable enable`). So you need two methods.

For value types, use the code provided by Joel Coehoorn:

```
public static T RequireNotNull<T>(T? obj,string? message) where T : struct {
    if (!obj.HasValue) {
        throw new Exception(message ?? "obj must not be null");
    }
    return obj.Value;
}
```

For reference types, use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!` to convince the compiler:

```
public static T RequireNotNull<T>(T? obj,string? message) where T : class {
    if (obj is null) {
        throw new Exception(message ?? "obj must not be null");
    }
    return obj!;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close:

```
public static T RequireNotNll<T>(T? obj,string? message) {
    if (obj == null) {
        throw new Exception(message ?? "obj must not null");
    }
    return obj.Value;
}
```

Comment: Will this compile?

Comment: thanks for you reply. I tested this code. and get a error, "'T' does not contain a definition "of 'Value'

Comment: This works vor value types (adding a `where T : struct`  constraint), but not for reference types.